# How to Prevent image from loading that comes from server side

Tags: javascript, html, angular, ionic-framework

I have API data with images, but due to internet problems or something else images are taking too much time to completely loaded.

Is there any way to prevent this loading because it looks bad when all data is loaded and images still taking time to display.

**menu.html**

```
<ion-card class="categories_item" *ngFor="let category of categories; let i = index;">
  <ion-grid>
    <ion-row>
      <ion-col size-md="2" size="4" class="img-zoom" align-self-center>
        <img [src]="category?.Picture1" (click)="imgView(category?.Picture1)" id="imgClickAble"
          class="imgClickAble" />
          .....
      </ion-col>

      <ion-col size-md="9" size="6" (click)="goToitemCategory(category.ID)">
        .....
      </ion-col>
    </ion-row>
  </ion-grid>
</ion-card>
```

I need to show something else until the complete image loaded like a place holder or I want to cache images for future use.

Comment: You can create a custom directive for `img` tag. When the URL of the image is received from API call, you can create a new image with `new Image()` and in the `onload` callback, you can replace the `src` attribute.

Comment: I would suggest to have some kind of flag that is set to true when you get the img from api and by default needs to be false. Then in your Template using *ngIf show hide the placeholder div and image conditionally

Comment: @AkshayBhat it can only help to hide or unhide the place holder but not help with the image loading speed

Comment: @HarunYilmaz can you please show me any example? that would be helpful

Comment: @Waqarali I posted a working example as an answer.

Comment: @HarunYilmaz thank you i will check it and let you know

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can hide original image and  use a place holder image in your loop and call original image `onload` function to hide place holder image and show actual image

```
<img src="placeholderurl" id="placeholder_{{i}}" >

<img [src]="category?.Picture1" class="hidden" id="original_{{i}}" (load)="onImageLoad(i)">
```

you onimageload function will look like

```
onImageLoad(idx){
  var orginalEle=document.getElementById(`original_${idx}`)
  var placeHolderEle=document.getElementById(`placeholder_${idx}`);
  placeHolderEle.classList.add('hidden');
  orginalEle.classList.remove('hidden');
}
```

[Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-w6ybqg)

Comment: i have tried it but it won't work, it displayed both images (placeholder and original) see the link. [link](https://ibb.co/q5cL8sN) i just need to prevent loading

Comment: @Waqarali did you add `.hidden` class in your css you have to add`.hidden{display:none}`

Answer (score 1):

I created a stackblitz project: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-dynamic-image-directive

First, create a custom directive. In the constructor, inject the `ElementRef` of the `img` tag and set the default value to `src` attribute.

And in `OnInit` callback, create a `new Image()` and set the new source. In the `onload` callback, set the new source to the `ElementRef` to the `img` tag

Hope this helps.

This is the directive:

```
import { Directive,  ElementRef, Input,Renderer2, OnInit} from '@angular/core';

@Directive({
  selector: '[appDynamicImage]'
})
export class DynamicImageDirective implements OnInit {

  @Input()
  dynamicSrc: string;

  private defaultSrc = 'https://via.placeholder.com/500x300';

  constructor(private elem: ElementRef,
  private renderer: Renderer2) { 
    this.setSource(this.defaultSrc);
  }

  ngOnInit(){
    setTimeout(() => { // just to mock loading time
      this.setAsyncSource(this.dynamicSrc);
    },2000)

  }

  setAsyncSource = (src: string) => {
    const dynamicImage = new Image();
    dynamicImage.onload = (e) => {
      console.log('onload', e)
      this.setSource(src);
    }

    dynamicImage.onerror = (e) => {
      console.log('Error happened', e)
    }

    dynamicImage.src = src;
  }

  setSource = (src: string) => {
    this.renderer.setAttribute(this.elem.nativeElement,'src',src);
  }

}
```

This is the template:

```
<img appDynamicImage [dynamicSrc]="'https://www.fillmurray.com/640/360'"/>
```